# Spring boot Getting domain name in @MessageMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

In spring boot, I can get the domain by `@RequestHeader String host` in `@RequestMapping`
But how can I do the same in `@MessageMapping` ?

eg.

```
@RequestMapping("/abc")
public String getHost(@RequestHeader String host) {
    return host;
}
```

I host my spring boot in, say, `www.example.com`, then when I access `www.example.com/abc` I get back `www.example.com`

I want to do the same thing inside `@MessageMapping` code

below is my `@MessageMapping` code.

```
@MessageMapping("/cba")
public void cba(SimpleRequest request, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor) {
    //System.out.println(host);
}
```

`SimpleRequest` is a request obj from my websocket client

I want to get the domain name inside my `@MessageMapping` code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can Try with `@Header` annotation
see below example

```
@MessageMapping("/optionalHeaders")
public void optionalHeaders(@Header(name="foo", required=false) String foo1, @Header("foo") Optional<String> foo2) {
  this.method = "optionalHeaders";
  this.arguments.put("foo1", foo1);
  this.arguments.put("foo2", (foo2.isPresent() ? foo2.get() : null));
}
```

Comment: then how to get the domain name in the method?